# time unit in tcpdump timestamps

Tags: python, timestamp, tcpdump, scapy

In Scapy (which uses tcpdump to capture packets), I'm extracting timestamps from a data packet that I sent and from the ICMP reply that I got from it.

```
>>> icmpPacket.time
1344448836.482289
>>> dataPacket.time
1344448832.707281
>>> RTT = icmpPacket.time - dataPacket.time
>>> RTT
3.775007963180542
```

What's the unit of time here? How can I have it in seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit of time is [seconds since the UNIX epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970). Use the [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) or [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) modules to interpret these, depending on your needs. The latter is a higher-level module.

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> icmpstamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1344448836.482289)
>>> icmpstamp
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 8, 20, 0, 36, 482289)
>>> print icmpstamp
2012-08-08 20:00:36.482289
>>> datastamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1344448832.707281)
>>> datastamp
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 8, 20, 0, 32, 707281)
>>> print datastamp
2012-08-08 20:00:32.707281
>>> difference = icmpstamp - datastamp
>>> difference
datetime.timedelta(0, 3, 775008)
>>> print difference
0:00:03.775008
```

Your `RTT` value is thus already the difference between the two timestamps in seconds.

Comment: If you convert the result of `icmpstamp - datastamp` to a string like this: `str(icmpstamp-datastamp)` you'll get a human friendly result of `'0:00:03.775008'`

Comment: Threw in a few print statements. The fact that `datetime` and `timestamp` have helpful string representations usually doesn't help much in an application, but do help debugging.

Comment: Thanks. Actually for the `dataPacket` I should have used the `time_stamp` field instead, which gets filled by `sr` in Scapy, and strangely not by Scapy's much simpler `send` function, which I was using on purpose as an alternative.    If I use that field above, I get results like `0.00022793`, and only rarely something like `0.1`. Nothing larger than that.